# Does Objective-C 2.0 garbage collection collect C structures?

Tags: c, objective-c, memory-management, garbage-collection, struct

What exactly does the Objective-C garbage collector collect? For example, if I'm writing a program in Objective-C 2.0, and I use some plain C structs, does my code need to worry about manually freeing that memory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For heap memory, you're on your own by default. Unless you allocate heap memory with [`NSAllocateCollectable`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW68) or [`NSReallocateCollectable`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW69), or explicitly hand a CoreFoundation object over to the garbage collector via an API like [`NSMakeCollectable`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW70), the GC has no idea about your memory, and won't manage it for you. Conversely, when GC is enabled, Objective-C objects created with `+alloc`/`-init` are managed by GC unless you explicitly tell it otherwise with a complementary API call.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/

Comment: +1 the Garbage Collection Programming Guide is one of the most fascinating pieces of technical writing I've ever read.

Comment: NSAllocateCollectable is the exact thing I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you use [`malloc()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/malloc.3.html) to allocate a structure on the heap, then I *really* doubt it (the man page doesn't mention anything about it, but it's possible that Apple rewrote `malloc` for the ObjC2 runtime).  If you use [`NSAllocateCollectable()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW68), then yes.

If the structure was created on the stack, then there's no need for collection, since it will be destroyed as soon as the frame exits.

Comment: +1 For mentioning what happens to structs allocated on the stack.